# Cygwin で インストールした Vim が起動しない

Tags: vim, cygwin, vi

cygwinでVimのパッケージを3つほどインストールしたのですがvi,vimと入力してもエラーは出ないのですがなにも出力されません。
`.bash_profile`に`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/vi`と記述し、`echo $PATH`で最後に`/usr/bin/vi`と出力されていたのでパスを通すことはできていると思います。

どなたか解決方法教えてください。

また、環境変数の設定のために`.bashrc`と`.bash_profile`をいじっていたところ今まではエイリアスが使用できていたのに使用できなくなりました。原因は何でしょうか??

**.bashrc**

```
alias c='cygstart'
alias ls='ls -fg --color=auto --show-control-chars'
alias df='df -h'
alias x='exit'
alias vi='/usr/bin/vi'
```

**.bash_profile**

```
. $HOME/.bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/vi
```

Comment: vim はどのようにインストールなさいましたか？

Comment: vimのインストールはsetup-x86.exeからvimのパッケージの追加をしました。最初は香り屋からインストールしたのですがcygwinからインストールしないと使用できないという記事をみましたので

Comment: エイリアスが使えなくなったというのは具体的にどうなったので、そう思われたのでしょうか？

Comment: 例えばc hello.cで-bash: c:コマンドが見つかりませんと出力されます。今まではこれでhello.cのファイルを開くことができました。

Comment: 単に`alias`とだけ実行すると、設定されているエイリアスの一覧が表示されます。自分で設定したエイリアスが表示されないなら、何かしらの原因で`.bashrc`や`.bash_profile`が読み込まれていません。`alias`コマンド自体が見つからないなら`cygwin`のインストールに問題があると思います。

Answer (score 3):

まず1つ勘違いされているのは、環境変数`PATH`に設定するのは(実行ファイル=コマンドの保存されている)**ディレクトリ名**です。もし`vi`が`/usr/bin/vi`に存在するなら、`PATH`に設定するときは
`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"`のように記述します。

ただし、`/usr/bin`は標準パスとして設定されているはずなので、Vimをインストールしたからといってユーザが改めて設定を追加する必要はありません。今回記述した`export PATH ...`はいったん削除したうえで、`which`コマンドで指定したコマンドにパスが通っているかを確認してみてください。

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

参考：
[which コマンド - 実行コマンドのフルパスを表示する：Linux基本コマンドTips](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1703/16/news020.html)

---

また、`vim`へのエイリアスであれば以下のような設定を行うのが定番です。

```
alias vi='vim'
```

Comment: export PARH...を削除してwhich vimとしたところ/usr/bin/vimと出力されました。あとaliasが使えなくなってしまった原因は何ですかね？今までは使えていたのですが...